# Bitmap.LockBits Overflow exception (large image)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I'm working on a problem that requires large image processing,
I'm using C# WPF for GUI and have a C++ GPU accelerated DLL backing the image processing.
I'd love to keep the interface unchanged and use pointers, the GUI is just for uploading and downloading the image.
However I've run into a problem with System.Drawing which seems to be caused by large sizes.

```
srcImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms, 
/*useEmbeddedColorManagement*/true,
/*validateImageData*/ false); // would throw "System.Overflowexception" if set to 'true',
//but doesn't seem to actually load Bitmap to RAM when set to 'false'
int width = srcImage.Width;
int height = srcImage.Height;
// LockBits throws "System.Overflowexception"
BitmapData srcImageData = srcImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, srcImage.PixelFormat); 
uint* ptr = (uint*)srcImageData.Scan0;
ExternalCPPCall(ptr, height, width);
srcImage.UnlockBits(srcImageData);
```

Image height x width

- 30720 x 30720 - (note - at 32bpp is well above 3.5GB) throws "System.Overflowexception", and any larger also throws
- 23040 x 23040 - (note - at 32bpp is just below 2GB) works just fine, and any smaller also works just fine

Also note - the 'ms' MemoryStream contains a PNG read from disk (which are usually about 1000 times smaller than resulting BMP)

Is the GDI+ backing System.Drawing a 32-bit library?? I'm compiling and running for 64-bit, my entire process chugs at 10GB usage just fine

Comment: I confused by your question. First of all, why are you using GDI+/Winforms API for WPF code? Secondly, what makes you think a finite device like your computer in a finite environment like our universe would not have some limits in terms of how much data can be handled by a single object? The exception you're describing seems perfectly reasonable, given the well-known limitations of GDI+.

Comment: I'm open for any alternatives that would allow me to load a PNG, display (fullsize or thumbnail) on screen for preview, decode it to 32bpp Bitmap and return a pointer to the pixel array

Comment: _"any alternatives"_ is simply too broad for Stack Overflow. The usual approach programs that need to handle arbitrarily large bitmaps use is to tile the data, so that it's actually only ever dealing with smaller portions of the whole bitmap at a time. The built-in bitmap handling APIs just aren't intended to support arbitrarily large bitmaps; the expectation is that the built-in APIs are good enough for most scenarios, and those who need to handle excessively large bitmaps will be able to justify the effort to research and implement suitable techniques.

Comment: Of course GDI+ doesn't know 64-bit. It's more than 15 years old.